# Akka: Actor isn't sending response

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-http

I want to return from Akka Actor a string response through api code. However, I'm keep getting timeouts and I don't have a clue what can be wrong with my code.

Actor:

```
object CredentialsActor {
  def props(implicit timeout: Timeout) = Props(new CredentialsActor)
}

class CredentialsActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case RegisterRequest => sender() ! "REGISTER"
  }
}
```

Api code:

```
class RestApi(system: ActorSystem, timeout: Timeout) extends Routes {
  implicit def requestTimeout: Timeout = timeout
  implicit def executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher
  def createCredentialsActor(): ActorRef = system.actorOf(CredentialsActor.props)
}

trait Routes extends CredentialsApi {
  val routes: Route =
    pathPrefix("app") {
      credentialsRoute
    }
}


trait CredentialsApi {
  def createCredentialsActor(): ActorRef
  implicit def requestTimeout: Timeout

  lazy val credentialsActor: ActorRef = createCredentialsActor()

  val credentialsRoute: Route =
    path("register") {
      get {
        pathEndOrSingleSlash {
          entity(as[RegisterRequest]) {
            request => {
              System.out.println(request.name, request.password, request.passwordRepeated)
              val response: Future[String] =
                (credentialsActor ? request).mapTo[String]
              complete(OK, response)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Request

```
final case class RegisterRequest(name: String, password: String, passwordRepeated: String)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't give the type of `RegisterRequest`, but if it is a `case class` then you want this:

```
case _: RegisterRequest => sender() ! "REGISTER"
```

As it stands you are matching the companion object rather than an instance of the class.

---

To extract the details from the request, do this:

```
case RegisterRequest(name, pw, pwRep) =>
  sender ! s"Register user $name with password $pw($pwRep)"
```

Comment: It works but it's strange because I didn't see this notation in example codes. And yes, RegisterRequest is a case class

Comment: Typically it would be `case RegisterRequest(arg1, arg2) =>` but I didn't know what args it took so I used the generic form `case req: RegisterRequest =>`. I used the placeholder `_` because you don't actually use the value of the request in the reply.

Comment: I get it, I added RegisterRequest code to my question so if you like can edit your answer for a version with arguments. It would look more suitable if you ask me :)